# Python Requests - Filling out Forms

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I am trying to get the html code on a website after putting in a parcel code on the first page.  However, the code below is not working.  All I get is the HTML print out for the home page of https://treasurer.maricopa.gov/

How do I get python to print the results of the website after putting in a parcel number such as 504-27-095?  I need the HTML from the results page.  Below is my code.

```
import requests
payload = {'txtParcelNumBook': '504', 'txtParcelNumMap': '27', 'txtParcelNumItem': '095', 'txtParcelNumSplit' : ''}
website = "https://treasurer.maricopa.gov/"
r = requests.post(website, data=payload)
print (r.text)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use a tool like the Browser Console in Firefox Developer Tools, you can see the actual requests made, which in this case clarifies that the URL actually being accessed is `https://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/?Parcel=xxxyyzzz`.

So your best bet would be something like this:

```
import requests
payload = '504' + '27' + '095' # or whatever
website = "https://treasurer.maricopa.gov/Parcel/?Parcel=" + payload
r = requests.get(website)
print(r.text)
```

Of course, in another rotation of IT staff, that will probably all change again.